# reactjs: how to setState multiple times synchronously for nested objects

Tags: reactjs

I am having a nested state as below:

```
this.state = {
  urls: {

    site1:[]
    site2:[]
    site3:[]

  }

}
```

I have a function which updates the urls i.e site1, site2 and site3

```
create_urls(sitename){
   ..... some logic to produce list of urls based on sitename
  this.setState({ urls:{
        ...this.state.urls,
        [sitename]: [url1,url2 ..... ]
      }
   });
}
```

now i am trying to fill the urls as below

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.create_urls("site1");
    this.create_urls("site2");
    this.create_urls("site3");
}
```

What I found is in the end only site3 urls are shown site1 and site2 are empty. I am expecting to fill all the three sites urls.

the sate is changing asynchronously. I could see it if i put a call back function with console.log in it.

So how can i input the urls of all the sites after mount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass a function to setState call, then you can safely synchronize previous state with the new one

```
create_urls(sitename){
    ....
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        urls:{
          ...prevState.urls,
          [sitename]: [url1, url2 ..... ]
        }
      }));
    ....
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create_urls(sitename){
   ..... some logic to produce list of urls based on sitename
   return urlArray

}

componentDidMount(){
   const url1Array = this.create_urls("site1");
   const url2Array = this.create_urls("site2");
   const url3Array = this.create_urls("site3");
    this.setState({ 
     site1: url1Array,
     site2: url2Array,
    site3: url3Array,

   });

}
```

Comment: so the only way to be sure is to assign all at a time

Comment: React batches setState operation. So using functional setState or setting all at a time is  good idea